# PHP Laravel application is working locally in Docker but not in Azure

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, azure, docker

I have a php laravel app that I am trying to containerize with Docker and serve in Azure as a Web App, database for my app is located in Azure(mysql database). When I launch the container locally I can login to my app and logs are written to the laravel.log file, but with the same image launched in Azure I cannot login and laravel.log is empty.

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:8.2

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- \
     --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

RUN mkdir /app

COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y zlib1g-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    unzip \
    dialog \
    npm \
    openssh-server \
    && echo "root:Docker!" | chpasswd \
    && chmod u+x ./docker-entrypoint.sh


RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql sockets mbstring exif pcntl bcmath gd

ADD . /app

COPY sshd_config /etc/ssh/

WORKDIR /app

RUN mkdir -p storage/app/public/uploads

RUN mkdir -p storage/app/public/uploads/clients

RUN mkdir -p storage/app/public/uploads/projects

RUN chown -R www-data.www-data /app

RUN chmod -R 755 /app

RUN chmod -R 777 /app/storage

RUN composer install

EXPOSE 8000 2222

ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

docker-entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
service ssh start
npm install --global gulp-cli@2.3
npm install
gulp
php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8000
```

I have checked permissions, installed mariadb-client to run query and it is working.

Comment: First obligation is to say `RUN chmod -R 777 /app/storage` is incorrect. `777` is never required and is always a security risk.

Comment: Second, what does "can't log in" mean? Have you verified that the user exists in your azure db? Are you using a built in login solution, etc?

Comment: To first, thanks for the advice, to second, if you read my question you will find out that the application is working completely fine.